# Баг админки в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. В админке ВП создаю, к примеру, запись, пишет что запись создана, перехожу на страницу со всеми записями, её там нет, обновляю страницу - она появилась. Нажимаю "удалить", отрабатывает скрипт и запись исчезает, но стоит обновить страницу и она снова есть. А если пытаюсь создать еще одну запись, то она просто перезаписывает прошлую. Ситуация аналогичная со всем остальным контентом, в том числе и с плагинами, и даже тему нормально поменять не могу, все отрабатывает только после обновления страницы или не отрабатывает вообще.

Пробовал выключать плагины, использовать дефолтную тему - ничего не помогает.

К сожалению не могу точно сказать после чего это произошло, были правки и по верстке и по формам, но в любом случае все правки применялись к конкретной теме. Отслеживал данные в БД - там всё более логично, если скрипт выдал успешное удаление, а на деле не удалил, то в БД запись неизменно существует, если добавляю новую запись, то в БД все появляется.

Я в ВП новичок и не могу просто взять и расковырять движок, может кто-то сталкивался или может просто направить хоть в каком файле поискать? Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Переустанови вордпресс и залей тему заново... Если не помогло, значит то, что правили в теме и создало баг - ищи в исходниках, что меняли и могло привести к таким последствиям (возможно какая–то самописная ф-я перехватывает соединения с БД при определенном хуке).